# Error while build apk

Tags: java, android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Akash\Desktop\android\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Akash.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-25.2.0.aar\876e5d10a24579a64796f25edbd33794\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.class]))

```
App Gradle :
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {`enter code here`
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.razorworld.bike"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }


    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding `{exclude module: 'support-v4'}` also to the other dependancies to check if any of them also adds the `support-v4` module?

Comment: Still no luck same error